# Handling exception in blocking library code in Akka

Tags: akka

I have a pool of DB Worker actors behind a router that does blocking DB operations, via a
Dao. Inserting ("putting") foo objects into the Dao throws DuplicateKeyException if you
try to insert the same foo twice. In that case I want to respond with a DuplicateFoo(foo)
message; upon success, I want to respond with FooAdded(foo). Here's how I've done that; is
there a better way?

```
def receive = {
  case PutFoo(foo) =>
    try {
      dao.put(foo)
      sender ! FooAdded(foo)
    } catch {
      case DuplicateKeyException(_) =>
        sender ! DuplicateFoo(foo)
    }
}
```

The Dao is OK to continue handling requests after throwing a DuplicateKeyException, so I
feel there isn't really a need to restart the worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the theoretical perspective, what you are doing is a "contains" check and then "put" or "notify". From the practical perspective, how it is implemented is "put" and if hell breaks loose "notify".

Since there is **no unexpected behavior** in theory, the implementation of `put` **in case of failure** is not ideal. If uniqueness is desired, a "contains" check should be expected, so `put` (or `PutFoo` in your scenario) should return a Status(Success|Failure), even if it tries to "put" and catches `DuplicateKeyException` internally . Take `Boolean`, or `Option` or `Either` or `Try` or your own status ADT for this, but do not throw an exception for something you expect to happen from time to time.

If there is no exception, there is no need to restart the worker, but I guess your gut was trying to tell you this all along. ;)

Comment: Well, if the DAO just wants to throw an exception and cannot be convinced otherwise, then I think his solution is completely fine. Akka is not dogmatic: if you really want to use exceptions to signal alternative expected outcomes (in contrast to exceptional ones) then go ahead. Just don’t complain that it does not look pretty ;-)

Comment: His solution is actually what I tried to describe (sry if that was not clear). His implementation does not signal alternative behavior with exceptions. He uses a status kinda thing `FooAdded` | `DuplicateFoo`, which is a perfect solution. ;) I'll edit my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Oh, seems I sounded harsh when I didn't mean to: I only wanted to say that if `put` is a given and cannot be changed, then catching exceptions in `receive` is okay even though that is a rather uncommon thing to do otherwise.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will change the dao to just return true/false. I'll leave exceptions for the "hey, where's my DB gone to?" scenario :-)